# How to manage state in a tree component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, tree, reactjs

I've been struggling this for a couple of days, trying to figure out the "react" way to do it.

Basically, I have a tree, a list of lists (of lists ...) that can be arbitrarily nested, and I want a component that will display this and also enable rearrangement.

Here's my data:

```
var data = [{
      id: 1
    }, {
      id: 2, children: [
        {
          id: 3, children: [{id: 6}]
        }, {
          id: 4
        }, {
          id: 5
        }]
    }]
```

My first pass was to just have a single "tree" component that builds the nested lists of DOM elements in its render function ([look at the code here](https://github.com/notablemind/tree/blob/fa9cd0af481204aef36ab89d162cc03dd1dbc8b1/index.jsx#L96)). That actually worked pretty well for small numbers of elements, but I want to be able to support hundreds of elements, and there was a very high re-render cost when an element was moved within the tree (~600ms when there were a few hundred elements).

So I think I'll have each "node" of the tree be it's own instance of this component. But **here's my question (sorry for the long intro):**

Should each node dynamically query for the list it's children's IDs from a central "database" and store that in state? Or should the top-most node load the whole tree and pass everything down through props?

I'm still trying to wrap my mind around how state & props should be handled & divvied up.

Thanks

Comment: Everything is a Tree here, right? You could reuse the Tree component to make it have Tree children instead of treating one as top-level. I haven't tried recursive rendering, but it should work. For every Tree component, render its immediate children and pass those children their children, etc. Also, make sure you set the `key` attribute on components in a loop so React can keep track of them.

Comment: oh the "key" attribute? Hadn't seen that anywhere in the docs. I'll try that out

Comment: The "key" attribute is not apparent, but it is mentioned in the [Dynamic Children](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children) section of the Components docs.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I wanted to try out the tree structure with React and came up with a simple component that hides subtrees when you click on `<h5>`. Everything is a `TreeNode`. Is this similar to what you were thinking?

You can see it in action in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ssorallen/XX8mw/

**TreeNode.jsx**:

```
var TreeNode = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      visible: true
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    var childNodes;
    if (this.props.node.childNodes != null) {
      childNodes = this.props.node.childNodes.map(function(node, index) {
        return <li key={index}><TreeNode node={node} /></li>
      });
    }

    var style = {};
    if (!this.state.visible) {
      style.display = "none";
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h5 onClick={this.toggle}>
          {this.props.node.title}
        </h5>
        <ul style={style}>
          {childNodes}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  },
  toggle: function() {
    this.setState({visible: !this.state.visible});
  }
});
```

**bootstrap.jsx**:

```
var tree = {
  title: "howdy",
  childNodes: [
    {title: "bobby"},
    {title: "suzie", childNodes: [
      {title: "puppy", childNodes: [
        {title: "dog house"}
      ]},
      {title: "cherry tree"}
    ]}
  ]
};

React.render(
  <TreeNode node={tree} />,
  document.getElementById("tree")
);
```

Comment: I can't pass the whole tree at start, would you mind to see my question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935756/how-to-implement-a-self-contained-component-in-react-redux

Answer (score 5):

Seems like it'd be nicer to pass everything down as props, as this will prevent you from the trouble of managing individual insertion/deletion. Also, like the comments said, the `key` attributes prevents a huge chunk of unnecessary re-rendering.

You might want to check this link: http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/11/05/thinking-in-react.html. It describes the kind of dilemma you're having and how to approach it.

*(Coincidentally, I've made a react tree view a while ago: https://github.com/chenglou/react-treeview. Take whatever you want from it!)*

Answer (score -1):

Here is a quick example of how to create a treeview using React and Flux.
http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/5510d81be1ce52d00e93da55

The React component is recursive and state is managed using Flux.