# How to implement a self contained component in react redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, redux, react-redux

I am building a file manager webui base on react redux(My purpose is to master react and redux through this project)

As you know, a file manager need a tree explorer.I want to build a component which can contain it self and each has self state. like below:

`TreeNode` can contain children  which are `TreeNode` too.Each `TreeNode` hold its state `{path, children_nodes, right .....}`, `children_nodes` is get from server, `path` is passed by parent. That's what I imagine.
Struct like:

```
App:
TreeNode
--TreeNode
----TreeNode
----TreeNode
TreeNode
TreeNode
--TreeNode
TreeNode
--TreeNode
----TreeNode
----TreeNode
```

---

But trouble come here, because redux `connect` store to the tree root, all node under the root receive same state...

For example, I have a `OPEN_NODE` action, which is design to trigger `getFileList fucntion` base this node's path and set this node's `state.open` to `true`.(note: `getFileList fucntion` not implement yet, just give fake data for now)
The screen shot:
[image]

Click each element , but `states are equal`.

My code:

containers/App.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import TreeNode from '../containers/TreeNode';
import Home from '../containers/Home';
import * as NodeActions from '../actions/NodeActions'

export default class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    // this will update the nodes on state
    this.props.actions.getNodes();
  }

  render() {
    const { nodes } = this.props
    console.log(nodes)
    return (
      <div className="main-app-container">
        <Home />
        <div className="main-app-nav">Simple Redux Boilerplate</div>
        <div>
          {nodes.map(node =>
            <TreeNode key={node.name} info={node} actions={this.props.actions}/>
          )}
        </div>

        {/*<Footer />*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    nodes: state.opener.nodes,
    open: state.opener.open
  };
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(NodeActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

containers/TreeNode.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import classNames from 'classnames/bind'
import * as NodeActions from '../actions/NodeActions'

export default class TreeNode extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.props = {
      open: false,
      nodes: [],
      info:{}
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    let {open} = this.props
    if (open) {
      this.props.actions.closeNode()
    } else {
      this.props.actions.openNode()
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { actions, nodes, info } = this.props
    return (
      <div className={classNames('tree-node', { 'open':this.props.open})} onClick={ () => {this.handleClick()} }>
        <a>{info.name}</a>
        {nodes &&
          <div>{nodes.map(node => <TreeNode info={node} />)}</div>
        }
        {!nodes &&
          <div>no children</div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TreeNode.propTypes = {
  open:PropTypes.bool,
  info:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  nodes:PropTypes.array,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

actions/NodeActions.js

```
import { OPEN_NODE, CLOSE_NODE, GET_NODES } from '../constants/NodeActionTypes';

export function openNode() {
  return {
    type: OPEN_NODE
  };
}

export function closeNode() {
  return {
    type: CLOSE_NODE
  };
}


export function getNodes() {
  return {
    type: GET_NODES
  };
}
```

reducers/TreeNodeReducer.js

```
import { OPEN_NODE, CLOSE_NODE, GET_NODES } from '../constants/NodeActionTypes';

const initialState = {
  open: false,
  nodes: [],
  info: {}
}

const testNodes = [
  {name:'t1',type:'t1'},
  {name:'t2',type:'t2'},
  {name:'t3',type:'t3'},
]


function getFileList() {
  return {
    nodes: testNodes
  }
}


export default function opener(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case OPEN_NODE:
    var {nodes} = getFileList()
    return {
      ...state,
      open:true,
      nodes:nodes
    };
  case CLOSE_NODE:
    return {
      ...state,
      open:false
    };
  case GET_NODES:
    var {nodes} = getFileList()
    return {
      ...state,
      nodes:nodes
    };
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

For complete code, see my github https://github.com/eromoe/simple-redux-boilerplate

I don't see an example cover such component, and google result nothing helpful.
Any idea to overcome this?

**update**:
I see this [How to manage state in a tree component in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503559/how-to-manage-state-in-a-tree-component-in-reactjs)

But the solution is pass the whole tree to state, can not use in file manager.

Comment: Look at [computing derived data](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html) in Redux.

Answer (score 1):

I'm implementing a Github like app using React and Redux.

For now, I only list repositories and show its files as well as navigate through them.

I don't know if this is considered a good or bad practice, but this is how I implemented my Tree component.

Inside each Tree Component, I have a Link to itself. And I pass some data on the route, so I'm able to get the next tree when I render it.

[image: App]

**Component**

```
class Tree extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.renderList = this.renderList.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getTree(this.props.params.sha);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.params.sha !== this.props.params.sha) {
      this.props.getTree(nextProps.params.sha);
    }
  }

  renderList(file) {
    return (
      <tr key={ file.sha }>
        { file.type == 'tree'
       ? <td><Link to={`/repository/${this.props.params.repoName}/tree/${file.path}/${file.sha}`}>{ file.path }</Link></td>
       : <td><Link to={`/repository/${this.props.params.repoName}/blob/${file.sha}/${file.path}`}>{ file.path }</Link></td>}
      </tr>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const treeFile = this.props.tree;
    const fileName = this.props.params.path;

    return (
      <div className="row">
        <h3>{ fileName }</h3>
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <table className="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <tbody>
              { isEmpty(treeFile.tree) ? <tr>Loading</tr> : treeFile.tree.map(this.renderList) }
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Tree;
```

**Action**

```
const setTree = (tree) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.GET_TREE,
    tree
  };
};

export const getTree = (sha) => {

  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { repository, profile } = getState();
    const repo = GitHubApi.getRepo(profile.login, repository.name);

    repo.getTree(sha, function(err, data) {
      dispatch(setTree(data));
    });
  }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = "";

export const tree = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.GET_TREE:
      return getTree(state, action);
  }
  return state;
}

const getTree = (state, action) => {
  const { tree } = action;
  return tree;
}
```

For the complete code, you can check my repository on github

https://github.com/glundgren93/Github-redux

Answer (score 0):

All of your `TreeNode` has the same state from redux because your `mapStateToProps` for all of them are same.

`mapStateToProps` can take `ownProps` (the `props` of the wrapped component) as second parameter. You can use it to distinguish your `TreeNodes`. In your case, `path` is a good option.

considering writing a state selector like this `getChildrenNodes(state, path)` and return the nodes accordingly.

You may want to consider reading through redux docs first, especially this seciont: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html